# Detecting if a bottle has a label

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

[image][image][image]I am currently doing a bit of computer vision using openCv. I have a sample of bottles a label on it. I am trying to determine when a bottle does not have a label on it.
The label is rectangular in shape.

I have done an edge detection using Canny.I have tried  using findcountour() to detect if a bottle has an inner contour(this would represent the rectangular label).

Comment: Could you give some more details..? Eg, what have you tried so far, example images, etc..?

Comment: @scap3y I have done an edge detection using Canny.I am trying to use findcountour() to detect if a bottle has an inner contour(this would represent the label).

Comment: Check this out: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2406/how-to-flatten-the-image-of-a-label-on-a-food-jar.. The question is very similar to yours expect that they have solved it using Mathematica (the code can be easily ported to OpenCV, though.. HTH

Comment: @scap3y Thanks. I need something much simpler because I want to learn from the ground up.

Comment: I am still unsure about what you exactly need.. Could you be specific, please..? I have already handed you the solution to your problem..

Comment: @scap3y I have added an image of my bottle.

Comment: In the link I posted, just stop after the first step and it should be fine. Do a threshold() check on *labelMask* and if it is higher than a particular threshold (in accordance with the type of images you are going to use), the bottle has a label..

Comment: @scap3y Thanks. I just don't understand the mathematica code.How do I choose a labelmask?

Comment: Can you share couple more bottle images with and without label (10 each) in a zip file?

Comment: @guneykayim I have added the extra image

Comment: If all images look like this, there can be very simple solution(s). I need to see more images. Does all have green label? Does all bottles are in same shape? etc. You need to provide more images to get an accurate answer..

Comment: @guneykayim The labels could be any colour.The shape of the bottle are all the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your problem is this simple, just place reduce your image using a rectangle.

```
cv::Mat image = imread("image.png");
cv::Rect labelRegion(50, 200, 50, 50);
cv::Mat labelImage = image(labelRegion);
```

Then decompose your image region into three channels.

```
cv::Mat channels[3];
cv::split(labelImage, channels);

cv::Mat labelImageRed = channels[2];
cv::Mat labelImageGreen = channels[1];
cv::Mat labelImageBlue = channels[0];
```

Then threshold each of these one channeled images and count number of zero/nonzero pixels.

```
I'm not providing code for this part!
```

If you don't have label on the image then each channel has values bigger then ~200 (you should check this). If there is a label, then you will see different result when counting zero/nonzero pixels from the non labeled one.

Comment: @guneykayim  Thanks.I would try it out

Comment: just that this method is susceptible to lighting conditions where shadows on the bottle might be mistaken for labels by the algorithm.

Comment: Yeah you're right, that's why I asked from sample images, but he did not provide anymore :) I think this solution is sufficient for these images.

Comment: That's a good solution, using edge detection would be much more sensitive to noise. If you want something even more sophisticated, you can use color histograms and build a training dataset for classification.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    Mat img=imread("c:/data/bottles/1.png");
    Mat gray;
    cvtColor(img,gray,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    resize(gray,gray,Size(50,100));
    Sobel(gray,gray,CV_16SC1,0,1);
    convertScaleAbs(gray,gray);
    if(sum(gray)[0]<130000)
    {       
        cout<<"no label";
    }else{
        cout<<"has label";
    }
    imshow("gray",gray);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ..Where did you get the value 130000 from ?

Comment: guessed...from the bottle that does not have label. it can be higher since there is a large margin between labelled bottles and not labelled ones. do `cout << sum(gray)` to find out

Comment: Can you please explain your algorithm.I don not understand it properly

Comment: it is based on the observation that labels produce more edges(regardless of whether the labels have text or not) and that your images orientations' are roughly fixed so that it is actually possible to directly compare the sum of edge magnitudes. normally for sobel, x and y derivatives are squared,summed and then squaredrooted(which is actually getting abs value). but here just doing y is better and sufficient(based on the images). but the sobel responses are have postive and negative values in it so we cant simply sum them since they will cancel out. convertscaleabs does it for you

Comment: resizing is necessary to ensure that gradient magnitudes are comparable. the choice of 130000 is very arbitary and i cant say this method will work for all your images since i havent seen all of them. but i can say with pretty good confidence(if all your images are indeed similar to what you have given) that if you calculate this value for all your images, it should be possible to find a number that perfectly split labelled and non-labelled images.

Comment: you can have more reliability by only doing this for the lower half of the image since for non-labelled bottles, it produce almost no response. an alternative explanation is this method is comparable to doing canny edge and then counting the number of white pixels. more pixels mean greater chance of being a labelled bottle. but it does it in fewer steps than canny edge

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. I have learnt a lot from your explanation.

Comment: This is a good answer in conjunction with the explanation in the comments, but that explanation would fit much better into the answer itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it should be enough to just see if there is text present on the bottle or not (if yes, then it has a label and vice versa).. You could check out a project like [THIS](http://funkybee.narod.ru/).. There are numerous papers in this area; some of the more famous ones are done by the Stanford CV group - [1](http://www.stanford.edu/~hchen2/papers/ICIP2011_RobustTextDetection.pdf) and [2](http://www.stanford.edu/~dwu4/ICDAR2011.pdf)..

HTH

Comment: I think this solution is an overkill, we first need to see more images.. Maybe not all labels has text on it.

Comment: I think this would give the most robust solution (for different bottle shapes+colors)..

Comment: Maybe, but it is a sophisticated solution for this problem, as Jack explained.

Answer (score 1):

guneykayim suggested image segmentation which I feel would be the easiest method. I am just adding a little bit more...

my suggestion is that you convert your BGR image into YCbCr and then look for values within the Cb and Cr channels to match the color of your label. This will allow you to easily segment out colors even if lighting conditions on the bottle change (a darkly lit bottle will end up having white regions appear dark gray and this can be a problem if you have gray colored labeling)

something like this should work in python:

```
# Required moduls
import cv2
import numpy

# Convert image to YCrCb
imageYCrCb = cv2.cvtColor(sourceImage,cv2.COLOR_BGR2YCR_CB)

# Constants for finding range of label color in YCrCb
# a, b, c and d need to be defined
min_YCrCb = numpy.array([0,a,b],numpy.uint8) 
max_YCrCb = numpy.array([0,c,d],numpy.uint8)

# Threshold the image to produce blobs that indicate the labeling
labelRegion = cv2.inRange(imageYCrCb,min_YCrCb,max_YCrCb)

# Just in case you are interested in going an extra step
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(labelRegion, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw the contour on the source image
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > minArea: # minArea needs to be defined, try 300 square pixels
        cv2.drawContours(sourceImage, contours, i, (0, 255, 0), 3)
```

the function cv2.inRange() will also work incase you decided to work with BGR image.

**Reference:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr